# PostgreSQL 9.1 adminpack install

Tags: postgresql

everywhere I see guides for postgre, it seems to be on version 8.4. In that case the instruction is:

```
sudo -u postgres psql < /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/adminpack.sql
```

that location doesn't exist in the 9.1 directory apparently.

Can anyone point me how to get it working (needed for pgadmin)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

admin pack can be found in `/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension`

To install

`sudo -u postgres psql`

`CREATE EXTENSION adminpack;`

Also to see a list of installed extensions `select * from pg_extension;`

Comment: this was more or less it. I was attempting to accomplish this with the user that was the owner of the database when in fact it appears that the default user, the one with superuser status, was required to do it.

Answer (score 10):

The answer above works great. You just have to remember that you need to do this for every database, as the extensions are installed per database.
The instructions above install the extensions in the database named `postgres`. To install it in your database just switch to your database:

`\c yourdb`

and repeat the process:

    `CREATE EXTENSION adminpack`

On Ubuntu the admin pack is in the postgresql-contrib package.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you haven't installed `contrib`:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib
```

To iterate over several databases:

```
sudo su postgres;
for db in $(psql -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false;" | sed '1,2d' | head -n -2 | grep -v '^ postgres$'); do
  echo "Adding adminpack to ${db}"
  psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION adminpack;" ${db};
done
```

As a one(ish)-liner:

```
sudo su postgres;
for db in $(psql -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false;" | sed '1,2d' | head -n -2 | grep -v '^ postgres$'); do psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION adminpack;" ${db}; done
```